# Editing Word 2003 template with custom toolbar in Word 2007

Tags: vba, ms-word

I only have Word 2007 and a Word 2003 template (.dot file).

When I open it, I can see it has macro's in it, stored in modules. I can also see that the template adds buttons to the add-ins tab in the ribbon.

How can I modify these buttons? Like the text or which macro each button triggers?

As a test I deleted all macros in the template, saved it, restared it, and it still gave me custom buttons in the Add-in tab. Of course if I press those buttons, it gives me error that the macro is not there. Which is fune. Then, if I view the template's code (Alt-F11), there is really no code at all. Also no Add-in is loaded (as seen in the Word options > Add ins window). So how does the Word 2003 template know which buttons to load? Where is the custom toolbar info stored in the Word 2003 template?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure i fully understood your question. Yet, here are a few elements.

**Modify the buttons generated by a macro**

You have to change the vba code. See :

- this link for Word 2003 : http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/custom-menus.htm
- this link for Word 2007+ : http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm

**Buttons already loaded**

If your custom buttons still appear after you deleted the code :

1. i'd think that you missed some part of the code to delete, can you re-check ? in every module of the doc
2. are you sure you didn't save a doc instead of saving the template ?

If these tips doesn't answer your question, please give us some more info on your problem or if possible, give us the template you are using.

Regards,

Max